# Как мне разобраться с методом и его свойством?

Tags: ооп, joomla, php

Есть большой класс в котором описан вот такой метод:

```
/**
     * Return the title of the page.
     *
     * @return  string
     *
     * @since    11.1
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }
```

в начале класса, как я понимаю, описывается свойство description:

```
/**
     * Document description
     *
     * @var    string
     * @since  11.1
     */
    public $description = '';
```

Метод getDescription() берет первые 200 символов статьи и записывает их в meta тег description. Но вопрос в том, как мне сделать, чтобы метод getDescription() брал больше символов чем 200? Помогите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по приведенному коду метод `getDescription()` ничего не делает с символами статьи, а просто возвращает значение поля `description`. Ищите, кто заносит значение в него.